# java two dimensional ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I'm working on a school project that involves making a tic tac toe game with adjustable dimensions. I'm encountering an error in my button-press handling code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at tictac.TicTacEvent.b(TicTacEvent.java:109)
at tictac.TicTacEvent.actionPerformed(TicTacEvent.java:67)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I would normally think that this is caused by my calling an index outside of an array's set parameters, but i cant find this in my code:

```
void b(int n)
{
    // code to change n to array indices
    // indice positions
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    int counter = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= (d - 1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= (d - 1); j++)
        {
            if (n == counter)
            {
                x = j;
                y = i;
                gui.blank1.setText("" + x + " " + y + "\n"); // debugging
                break; // values found, exit loop
            }
            else
            {
                // increment counter
                counter ++;
            }
        }
    }
    counter = 1;

    clicks++;
    if ((clicks % 2) == 1) // not divisible by two
    {
        gui.boxes[x][y].setIcon(a);
        check[x][y] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        gui.boxes[x][y].setIcon(b);
        check[x][y] = 2;
    }

    winner();
}
```

the error occurs when i call `gui.boxes[x][y]`, as well as when i call the `b(n)` function
thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You also need to learn to read a stack trace. Instead of randomly looking for the problem, read it: it tells you that the problem happens at line 109 of TicTacEvent.java.

Comment: and reading the Exception further (actually the 1st line), it says that the index that caused the Exception has the value zero (0) - apparently the array was created with zero capacity like in `new Object[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace says that the index that was out of bounds was 0. For that to be possible, the array has to have zero length. therefore, either `gui.boxes.length` is zero or for some value of `x`, `gui.boxes[x].length` is zero. Check both.